# Skipping Taraweeh for one day or two days

Tags: taraweeh

Assalamualaikum,
Can we skip taraweeh,not for whole Ramadan but for one day or two days?

Comment: What hinders you to skip it?

Comment: Taraweeh is not mandatory, it's Sunnah but it's highly encouraged to participate in.